# threeJS, OBJ's color not show up

Tags: three.js

I have loaded the .obj file and set the color to its details, but it only shows up all black

```
const loader = new OBJLoader();
loader.load( src, function ( obj ) {
  obj.traverse( function ( child ) {
    child.material.color.setHex(0xFF0000);
    console.log("child.material.color: ", child.material.color);
  }
}

scene.add(obj);

...

var hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
hemiLight.position.set( 0, 300, 0 );
scene.add( hemiLight );

var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
dirLight.position.set( 75, 300, -75 );
scene.add( dirLight );
```

the console.log print out the object Color: {r: 1, g: 0, b: 0, isColor: true}

So, is there anything I have missed?

Comment: Can you please verify whether the OBJ asset defines vertex normals or not?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the way you have it, you're not actually adding it to the scene because 'obj' ref is only valid within the (async) callback.

If you move scene.add(obj) into your callback it should work.

I created a codepen:
https://codepen.io/flatworldstudio/pen/ExNpedV

Look for this bit:

```
 loader.load(src, function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
    scene.add(obj);
    ref = obj;
    obj.traverse(function (child) {
      if (child.material) {
        child.material.color.setHex(0xff0000);
        console.log("child.material.color: ", child.material.color);
      }
    });
  });
```